# Installing Talend MDM Server on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, mdm, talend

While Ubuntu Server 12.04 64-bit is a [recommended operating system](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforMDMInstallationandUpgradeGuide53EN/1.3+Compatible+Platforms) for Talend MDM Server I couldn't find any installation instructions for this OS. So I had to build my own. Any proposals and amendments to the instruction below are appreciated.

- Install Oracle Java 7 (see complete instruction [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html))

  ```
  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java  
  $ sudo apt-get update  
  $ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
  ```
- Create system group 'talend'

  `$ sudo addgroup --system talend`
- Create system user 'talend' and include it into 'talend' group. Note we use here /opt/talend directory both as home directory for 'talend' user and installation directory for the server

  `$ sudo adduser --system --ingroup talend --home /opt/talend --disabled-login talend`
- Setup JAVA_HOME as system-wide environment variable:

  `$ echo JAVA_HOME=\"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/\" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment`
- Copy TOS_MDM-Server-*.jar file on machine to be MDM Server
- Start Talend MDM Server installer:

  `$ sudo -u talend java -jar TOS_MDM-Server-*.jar -console`
- Follow instructions on screen and point installer to unpack software into /opt/talend directory.
- Start server to check it's working

  `$ sudo -u talend /opt/talend/jboss-4.2.2.GA/bin/run.sh`
- Stop MDM server pressing Ctrl+C in console

Keep reading if you need to start your MDM Server on system boot up. I decided to use Upstart for that.

- Create new file

  `$ sudo vim /etc/init/talend-mdm-server.conf`
- Add to the job definition file text like this:

  ```
  description "Talend MDM Server"  

  start on runlevel [2345]     
  stop on runlevel [016]     

  respawn     

  setuid talend          

  script     
      exec /opt/talend/jboss-4.2.2.GA/bin/run.sh -b 0.0.0.0     
  end script
  ```
- Check if it's working

  `$ sudo start talend-mdm-server`
- Stop MDM server on success

  `$ sudo stop talend-mdm-server`
- Reboot machine to make sure everything's working

  `$ sudo reboot`

Your Talend MDM Server instance should be running on system startup.

Comment: Even if the contents may be interesting, I don't see any real question here.

Comment: This is not question at all and it's offtopic for StackOverflow. I voted to close it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the non-question :

"*Where is the documentation for installing Talend MDM *Server* on a Linux Ubuntu 12 server ?*" :) could be :

Here is the Installation Guide (chapter 2.2.1) : https://help.talend.com/display/HOME/Talend+Open+Studio+for+MDM

and there, some notices about installing Talend MDM *Client* (ie *Studio*) on Ubuntu : http://www.talendforge.org/wiki/doku.php?id=doc:installation_on_ubuntu

Comment: In start message I described an installation of a **server** part.

Comment: See chapter 2.2.1 of "Talend Open Studio for MDM Installation and Upgrade Guide"